# The best way to read and process email's attachments in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

We have a few third-party companies sending us emails with CSV/excel data files attached to the emails. I want to build a pipeline (preferably in ADF) to get the attachments, load the raw files (attachments) to blob, process/transform them, and finally load the processed files to another dir in the blob.

To get the attachment, I think I can use the instructions (using Logic App) in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow). Then, trigger an ADF pipeline using storage trigger, get the file and process it and do the rest of the stuff.

However, first, I'm not sure how reliable storage triggers are?
Second, although it seems ok, this approach makes it difficult to monitor the runs and make sure things are working properly. For example, if the logic app doesn't read/load the attachments for any reason and fails, you can't pick it up in ADF as nothing has written in the blob to trigger the pipeline.

Anyway, is this approach good, or there are better ways to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to save attachments into a blob or something, you can schedule a ADF pipeline that imports every file in the blob every minute og 5 minute or so.

Does the files have same data structure everytime? (that makes things much easier)

It is most common to schedule imports in ADF, rather that trigger based on external events.

Comment: Thanks! But that doesnt answer my concern, Im still using Logic App + ADF. Also checking a blob every 5 min is not something Im looking for, a more optimized solution is what Im after.

Comment: Can you use Azure function to process the files?

Comment: The whole solution is 3 parts: 1) get email and save attachment to blob (logic app). 2) process the file (azure function either added to logic app or storage triggered using adf). 3) load the process file. All can be done in logic app  but as all my triggers and pipeline implemented in adf, I want to see if these can be done in adf. Again, the solution is the question not the part.